# Retain Core Data in unpublished app when upgrading iOS beta version

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have an app I am developing in Xcode beta that uses Core Data and is running on my iPad with iOS beta installed. When I upgrade the iOS beta to the new version, the app does not restore from iTunes along with all of the other apps. After running the app in Xcode using my iPad as the destination, the app has its previous user defaults restored, but any Core Data is lost.

Is there a way to back up this app's Core Data for restoration after the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

When we're talking about unpublished app there's no problem. You have to download app container (Xcode - Window - Devices), select the device, select the app, tap on 'settings' button below the list and select `Download Container`. Then after update just select `Replace Container` and give that downloaded one. This way you will keep not only `CoreData` but everything saved in app folder.

BTW: you may use this method to "swap" user data between few devices.

Ofc you may do it via code, but this is quicker for such rare situations and you won't forget to delete code later ;).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When I have another chance to test it out, I'll come back and accept the answer if it works.